# Regex ^.*[ ,\t]+ php

Tags: php, regex

I have a problem with this simple regex.

It works on Notepad++ and in Notepad but I can't use it on PHP, sure I write bad code, but it's more than 2 hours that I try to solve and I don't see the solution.
I have to manage Amazon report like this file.txt

```
SEM45-4C-CUPOLE B075FQGBXS  7438632301630
SEM60-6C-CUPOLE B075FLSCXJ  7438632301623
SEM80-8C-CUPOLE B075FPTVX1  7438632301616
```

I need only the last number `7438xxxxx`

I write in PHP the upload of this file

```
$string =  file_get_contents($_FILES['report']['tmp_name']);
$pattern = '/^.*[ ,\t]/';
$replacement = '';
$string = preg_replace($pattern,$replacement,$string);
echo  $string;
```

But it doesn't work and I always see all the content.
Could anyone help me?

Comment: Do you have to use regex? Are the numbers always the same length?

Comment: Why not use though? Isn't it a textbook use case of regex?

Comment: @Louis-MarieMatthews: _Why not use though? Isn't it a textbook use case of regex?_ No, http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php or `explode` or `substr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pattern with multiline modifier:

```
$pattern = '~^.*[ ,\t]~m';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `preg_match_all` instead.

```
$string =  file_get_contents($_FILES['report']['tmp_name']);
$pattern = '\d+(\v|\Z)/';
$results = [];
preg_match_all($pattern,$string, $results, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
echo $results[0];
```

And `$results[0]` contains an array of numbers, the ones you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Why replace everything *but* what you want instead of just capturing what you want?

```
$in = <<<_E_
SEM45-4C-CUPOLE B075FQGBXS  7438632301630
SEM60-6C-CUPOLE B075FLSCXJ  7438632301623
SEM80-8C-CUPOLE B075FPTVX1  7438632301616
_E_;

foreach(explode("\n", $in) as $line) {
    $parts = preg_match('/(\d+)$/', $line, $matches);
    printf("%s\n", $matches[1]);
}
```

Or just get the 3rd whitespace-delimited field:

```
foreach(explode("\n", $in) as $line) {
    $parts = preg_split('/\s+/', $line);
    printf("%s\n", $parts[2]);
}
```